# Jetpack Compose: Material Color disappears in switching between different orientation

Tags: android, kotlin, colors, android-jetpack-compose, landscape-portrait

I am new to Android Development and currently learning Jetpack Compose.
Recently, I started a simple Notes application using Room Database with MVVM Architecture. I am facing an issue of Note color disappearance while switching between different orientations (Note Title and Note Content remains intact). I am using ViewModel to remember the states.

If I start the application in Landscape orientation then Colors appear normally, but while switching the orientation Colors disappear, and switching back to landscape orientation make them visible again.

[image] [image]

Here is my ViewModel Class:

```
class NoteViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {

    val getAllNotes: LiveData<List<Note>>
    private val repository: NoteRepository

    init{
        val noteDao = NoteDatabase.getDatabase(application).noteDao()
        repository = NoteRepository(noteDao)
        getAllNotes = repository.getAllNotes()
    }

    fun addNote(note:Note){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
            repository.addNote(note)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Entity Class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "note_table")
data class Note(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id:Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "NoteTitle")
    val title:String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "NoteText")
    val text:String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "NoteColor")
    val color:Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "IsTodo")
    val isTodo:Boolean
){
    companion object{
        val noteColors = listOf(
            Color.White,
            Yellow300,
            Green300,
            Red300,
            Blue300,
            Magenta300,
        )
    }
}
```

this is my Note Card Composable

```
@Composable
fun NoteCard(
    modifier:Modifier = Modifier,
    noteTitle:String,
    noteContent:String,
    getNoteColorFromIndex:Int,
    currentNoteIndex:Int,

) {
    val noteColor by remember{mutableStateOf(noteColors[getNoteColorFromIndex])} //this noteColors is from Entity's Class Companion Object
    var noteState by remember{ mutableStateOf(NoteState.Collapsed)}
    val transition = updateTransition(targetState = noteState,label = "Expanded State")
    val arrowRotate by transition.animateFloat(
        label = "Arrow Rotation"
    ) { state ->
        when(state){
            NoteState.Collapsed -> 0f
            NoteState.Expanded -> 180f
        }

    }
    NoteCardView(
        noteTitle,
        noteContent,
        noteColor,
        currentNoteIndex,
        noteState,
        arrowRotate,
        modifier
    ){
        noteState = when(noteState){
            NoteState.Collapsed -> NoteState.Expanded
            NoteState.Expanded -> NoteState.Collapsed
        }
    }
}
```

And calling of above Composable using ViewModel

```
NoteCard(
    noteTitle = ListOfNotes[index].title,
    noteContent = ListOfNotes[index].text,
    getNoteColorFromIndex = ListOfNotes[index].color,
    currentNoteIndex = index
)
```

Comment: Where `note` in `noteColors[note]` came from? Maybe it should be `getNoteColorFromIndex` instead?

Comment: yes it is `getNoteColorFromIndex `. Sorry type mistake in the question. `noteColors[getNoteColorFromIndex]`

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out if I add a Toast message in NoteCard then it works fine ¯\*(ツ)*/¯

but it is not a proper solution